# subsetting R data after sorting

Tags: r, sorting, subset

I have a data table like this:

```
        datetime         EquipmentNumber Count Raw
1: 2012-11-28 16:00:00       100094233     1   2
2: 2012-11-30 10:00:00       100094233     2   2
3: 2012-11-30 11:00:00       100094233     0   0
```

and I want to get the highest 100 `Raw` values for each `EquipmentNumber` (there are 15)

I have sorted my data descending and for each `EquipmentNumber` like this:

```
vc.sorted <- VisitorCounters[order(EquipmentNumber, -Raw),]
```

but don't know how to subset these to have a data table showing the first 100 values of `Raw` for each `EquipmentNumber`.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table` (as the OP's dataset is `data.table`) in a compact and faster way.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(VisitorCounters)` - in case it is not a `data.table`), grouped by 'Equipmentnumber' and `order`ing 'Raw' in 'i', we get the first 100 rows with `head`.

```
library(data.table)
VisitorCounters[order(-Raw), head(.SD, 100), by = Equipmentnumber]
```

Or using `setorder`

```
setorder(VisitorCounters, Equipmentnumber, -Raw)[, head(.SD, 100), by = Equipmentnumber]
```

Using a reproducible example

```
set.seed(24)
dt1 <- data.table(id = rep(1:3, each = 3), value = rnorm(9))
setorder(dt1, id,-value)[, head(.SD, 1), by = id]
#   id     value
#1:  1 0.5365853
#2:  2 0.8474600
#3:  3 0.4445853
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be easily done with `dplyr` package

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(Equipmentnumber) %>% arrange(Raw, desc = T) %>% top_n(100)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `order` and `by`. Sort the data frame based on `Raw` column and then for every `EquipmentNumber` select top 100 rows.

```
mt <- VisitorCounters[order(VisitorCounters$Raw, decreasing = T), ]
by(mt, mt["EquipmentNumber"], head, n=100)
```

Comment: Yes sorry this is my first post ever on this site.

I have tried sorting with "by" but I always get an error message back.

vc.sorted <- VisitorCounters[order(-Raw), by(["EquipmentNumber"], head, n=100)]'

Error: unexpected '[' in "vc.sorted <- VisitorCounters[order(-Raw), by(["

What does mt stand for?

Comment: check the first step. `mt` is just a variable assigned to the sorted df.

Comment: Ok, well I tried with your code and for mt, the error comes back saying "Error in df$Raw : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable"

Comment: @Kiwi95 your dataset is `data.table`.  Some `data.frame` methods won't work with `data.table`..  Check my answer.

Comment: @Kiwi95 okay, here `df` is the dataframe that you are using. In your case it seems it is `VisitorCounters`. I have edited my answer. You can check now.

Comment: Yes this time mt worked thanks! But I think I need to key my data with setkey, I will check the R help

Comment: Yes thank you very much! There still is an error for some reason 

Error in setkeyv(x, cols, verbose = verbose, physical = physical) : 
  some columns are not in the data.table: -"Raw"

Comment: @kiwi95 You can use `setorder`  Please check my answer